# SQL query to sum all distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains informations about markets :

```
market_id | cashier_id | storekeeper_id

m1        | c1         | s1
m1        | c1         | s2
m1        | c1         | s9
m1        | c2         | s3
m2        | c7         | s5
m2        | c8         | s6
```

I also have the table cashier:

```
cashier_id | salary

c1         | 1100
c2         | 1100
c3         | 1100
c7         | 1220
c8         | 1150
```

and the table storekeeper:

```
storekeeper_id | salary
s1         | 1000
s2         | 1000
s3         | 1000
s5         | 1050
s6         | 1100
s9         | 1100
```

I want to write a query which finds the summary of salaries (both for cashiers and storekeepers) for each market.
The result should be like:

```
m1 6300
m2 4520
```

I tried to join the table market with the 2 other tables and use `SUM(DISTINCT)` on the salaries but this exclude employees with same salaries. Is there any other way I could do this ?

Comment: What formula did you use to calculate the results for m1 and m2?

Comment: I summed both cashier salary and storekeeper salary for each store,

Comment: then why m2 = 4250 ? instead of 1220 + 1150 + 1100 + 1100 = 4570

Comment: Its 1220 + 1150 + 1050 + 1100 = 4520

Answer (score 1):

You have a really, really bad data model, unless your intent is to say that a given cashier works multiple times in a single market.

That said, you can get what you want out of the data.  `union all` is your friend:

```
select m.market_id, sum(salary)
from ((select distinct m.market_id, c.cashier_id, NULL as storekeeper_id, c.salary
       from markets m join
            cashiers c
            on c.cashier_id = m.cashier_id
      ) union all
      (select distinct m.market_id, NULL, s.storekeeper_id, s.salary
       from markets m join
            storekeepers s
            on s.storekeeper_id = m.storekeeper_id
      )
     ) m
group by m.market_id
```

Comment: No, a cashier is working just one time for a single market. But in order to say that a store has more storekeepers than cashiers I have to repeat cashier_id .

Answer (score 1):

```
select market_id, sum(salary) from (
    select market_id, sum(salary) salary from 
    (select distinct market_id, cashier_id
    from markets)a
    join cashier b on a.cashier_id=b.cashier_id
    group by market_id
    union all
    select market_id, sum(salary) from
    (select distinct market_id, storekeeper_id
    from markets
     )b
    join storekeeper c on b.storekeeper_id=c.storekeeper_id
    group by market_id)c
group by market_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT k.mid, (sum(k.cs) + sum(k.s_sum))
from (SELECT market_id as mid, market.cashier_id as cid,
cashier.salary as cs, sum(storekeeper.salary) as s_sum
((from markets inner join cashier on markets.cashier_id=cashier.cashier_id) 
inner join storekeeper on markets.storekeeper_id=storekeeper.storekeeper_id)
group by markets.market_id,cashier.cashier_id) as k
group by k.mid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` to combine cashier and storekeeper salaries. From there a simple `GROUP BY` will get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT market_id, SUM(salary)
FROM (SELECT m.market_id, c.cashier_id, c.salary
      FROM market m
      INNER JOIN cashier c ON c.cashier_id = m.cashier_id
      UNION
      SELECT m.market_id, s.storekeeper_id, s.salary
      FROM market m
      INNER JOIN storekeeper s ON s.storekeeper_id = m.storekeeper_id) tmp
GROUP BY market_id
```